# Caliburn.Micro(.WP7) and Bing Maps Crashing

Tags: windows-phone-7, caliburn, caliburn.micro

I have an app that I'm upgrading from some beta bits - and my map screen is crashing. So to try to get to the bottom of it - I started a brand new - blank "Win Phone Application".

Referenced Caliburn.Micro (just built from new code last night) Version: caliburnmicro_1296ea635677 (from codeplex)

referenced Microsoft.phone.controls.map.dll

and in the MainPage I added

```
<Grid>
 <Maps:Map />
</Grid>
```

and I add a bootstrapper to app.xaml

```
<WP7:PhoneBootStrapper x:Name="bootstrapper" />
```

when the page runs in the phone emulator - the main page renders and I see a map of the world. if I click anywhere on the page - I get an unhandled exception of "The parameter is incorrect"

if I remove the

from the app.xaml - the map works correctly.

What do you think?

Thanks for any advice?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem with the latest source. Did the problem get resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

The key here - is that I had this setup and wroking with the Beta Templates - and it stopped working when I moved to the WinPhone RTM Templates in VS2010.

Caliburn does some work on my behalf, that was "ADDED" to the RTM templates - which were conflicting with each other. In the end This problem has/had nothing to do with the Bing Maps control - it just so happens that - that was my first screen - so that's where I was trying to solve the problem.

This was the ever so Not-Helpful exception:

```
The parameter is incorrect
```

Which, I'm pretty sure would happen on any screen - if you went to the upgrade path of templates, like I did. So here is what I had to remove - to get everything back to normal. In the new App.Xaml.cs - I removed (by commenting) in the App Ctor ...

```
// Phone-specific initialization
// InitializePhoneApplication();


// Global handler for uncaught exceptions. 
// UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;
```

And then I removed these method bodies, because it's just dead code after removing the InitializePhoneApplication() call from ctor ...

```
// Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
// This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
}

// Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
// This code will not execute when the application is first launched
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
}

// Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
// This code will not execute when the application is closing
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
}

// Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
// This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
}

// Code to execute if a navigation fails
private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
}

// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
}

#region Phone application initialization

// Avoid double-initialization
private bool phoneApplicationInitialized = false;

// Do not add any additional code to this method
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
        return;

    // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
    // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
    RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
    RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

    // Handle navigation failures
    RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

    // Ensure we don't initialize again
    phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
}

// Do not add any additional code to this method
private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
    if (RootVisual != RootFrame)
        RootVisual = RootFrame;

    // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
    RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
}

#endregion
```

Special Thanks to Rob for his help solving this mystery!